# BufferedReader can't read long line

Tags: java, json, parsing, reader

I am reading this file: https://www.reddit.com/r/tech/top.json?limit=100 into a BufferedReader from a HttpUrlConnection. I've got it to read some of the file, but it only reads about a 1/10th of what it should. It doesn't change anything if I change the size of the input buffer - it prints the same thing just in smaller chunks:

```
try{
    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int charsRead;
    char[] inputBuffer = new char[500];
    while(true) {
        charsRead = reader.read(inputBuffer);
        if(charsRead < 0) {
            break;
        }
        if(charsRead > 0) {
            sb.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead));
            Log.d(TAG, "Value read " + String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead));
        }
    }

    reader.close();

    return sb.toString();
} catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I believe the issue is that the text is all on one line since it's not formatted in json correctly, and BufferedReader can only take a line so long. Is there any way around this?

Comment: No effect - same 1/10th'ish of the file

Comment: Note: `StringBuilder` has an `append(char[], int, int)` which should be better than creating a `String`

Comment: You talk about reading **one line**, but I see no code related to the reading/processing of *lines*. All I see is code reading *blocks* of characters. If you want *lines*, **use the [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method**. It doesn't have a limit on the length of a line, other than available memory and the max length of a Java `String`.

Comment: Initially I was using readLine() with this method:
    String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

Since the whole text file is one line it seemed stupid having a while loop reading one line

Comment: is it possible that this part of the link is the problem: `...?limit=100` ?

Comment: No since that means 100 reddit entries, It only reads 10 entries. It remains at 10 entries when I change ?limit=100 to ?limit=200

Comment: *FYI:* Replace `sb.append(String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead))` with `sb.append(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead)`. It's a waste to create an intermediate String object.

Comment: "Since the whole text file is one line it seemed stupid having a while loop reading one line" - so just call `readLine()` once. What happens when you try that? Do you get everything you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read()` should continue to read as long as `charsRead > 0`. Every time it makes a call to read, the reader marks where it last read from and the next call starts at that place and continues on until there is no more to read. There is no limit to the size it can read. The only limit is the size of the array but the overall size of the file there is none.

You could try the following:

```
try(InputStream is = connection.getInputStream(); 
   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {

  int read = 0;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

  while((read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }

  return new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (Exception ex){}
```

The above method is using purely the bytes from the stream and reading it into the output stream, then creating the string from that.

Comment: I still don't see how this (while admitedly shorter and more concise) is any different from what the OP was doing. He's also reading the stream in a loop.

Comment: Janez Kuhar is correct, the code works well but still reads the same amount as it did before

Comment: *"`read()` is a stream"* Really? `InputStream` is a stream. `Reader` is a stream. `read()` is a method that can be called to read *from* the stream, but it is not the stream.

Comment: @Andreas fixed it. @Janez Kuhar. This is just a different way to do the same thing but acts on the raw bytes instead of from a buffered reader. There might be a char value that the `BufferedReader` doesnt like (highly doubt it though) but reading the raw bytes might handle it better.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe the issue is that the text is all on one line since it's not formatted in json correctly, and `BufferedReader` can only take a line so long.

This explanation is not correct:

1. You are not reading a line at a time, and `BufferedReader` is not treating the text as line based.
2. Even when you do read  from a `BufferedReader` a line at a time (i.e. using `readLine()`) the only limits on the length of a line are the inherent limits of a Java `String` length (2^31 - 1 characters), and the size of your heap.

<sup>Also, note that "correct" JSON formatting is subjective.  The JSON specification says nothing about formatting.  It is common for JSON emitters to not waste CPU cycles and network bandwidth on formatting for JSON that a human will only rarely read.  Application code that consumes JSON needs to be able cope with this.</sup>

---

So what is actually going on?

Unclear, but here are some possibilities:

1. A `StringBuilder` *also* has an inherent limit of 2^31 - 1 characters.  However, with (at least) some implementations, if you attempt to grow a `StringBuilder` beyond that limit, it will throw an `OutOfMemoryError`.  (This behavior doesn't appear to be documented, but it is clear from reading the source code in Java 8.)
2. Maybe you are reading the data too slowly (e.g. because your network connection is too slow) and the server is timing out the connection.
3. Maybe the server has a limit on the amount of data that it is willing to send in a response.

Since you haven't mentioned any exceptions and you always seem to get the same amount of data, I suspect the 3rd explanation is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that your default platform charset was UTF-8 and encoding problems were raised. For remote content the encoding should be specified, and not assumed to be equal to the default encoding on your machine.

The charset of the response data must be correct. For that the headers must be inspected. The default should be Latin-1, ISO-8859-1, but browsers interprete that
as Windows Latin-1, Cp-1252.

```
        String charset = connection.getContentType().replace("^.*(charset=|$)", "");
        if (charset.isEmpty()) {
            charset = "Windows-1252"; // Windows Latin-1
        }
```

Then you can better read bytes, as there is no exact correspondence to the number of bytes read and the number of chars read. If at the end of a buffer is the first char of a *surrogate pair*, two UTF-16 chars that form a Unicode glyph, symbol, code point above U+FFFF, I do not know the efficiency of the underlying "repair."

```
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
        while (true) {
            int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
            if (bytesRead < 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
        return out.toString(charset);
```

And indeed it is safe to do:

```
sb.append(inputBuffer, 0, charsRead);
```

(Taking a copy was probably a repair attempt.)

By the way `char[500]` takes almost twice the memory of `byte[512]`.

---

I saw that the site uses gzip compression in my browser. That makes sense for text such as json. I mimicked it by setting a request header **Accept-Encoding: gzip**.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://www.reddit.com/r/tech/top.json?limit=100");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    try (InputStream rawIn = connection.getInputStream()) {
        String charset = connection.getContentType().replaceFirst("^.*?(charset=|$)", "");
        if (charset.isEmpty()) {
            charset = "Windows-1252"; // Windows Latin-1
        }
        boolean gzipped = "gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding());
        System.out.println("gzip=" + gzipped);

        try (InputStream in = gzipped ? new GZIPInputStream(rawIn)
                : new BufferedInputStream(rawIn)) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            while (true) {
                int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead < 0) {
                    break;
                }
                if (bytesRead > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            return out.toString(charset);
        }
    }
```

**It might be for not gzip conform "browsers" the content length of the *compressed* content was erroneously set in the response.** Which is a bug.

Comment: Having implemented that it doesn't seem to have done anything. Still only getting 10 reddit entries as opposed to 100

Comment: I had an error, use getContentEncoding ("gzip") i.o. getContentType. I'll add soemthing to my answer

Comment: That much loss of data seems to indicate a bug in reddit, the response setting a Content-Length of the compressed data, though delivering the gzipped data. One could test that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using 3d party Http client. It could reduce your code literally to just a few lines and you don't have to worry about all those little details. Bottom line is - someone already wrote the code that you are trying to write. And it works and already well tested. Few suggestions:

1. [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) - A well known and popular Http client, but might be a bit bulky and complicated for a simple case like yours.
2. [Ok Http Client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) - Another well-known Http client
3. And finally, my favorite (because it is written by me) MgntUtils Open Source library that has Http Client. Maven artifacts can be found [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils), GitHub that includes the library itself as a jar file, source code, and Javadoc can be found [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)  and JavaDoc is [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html)

Just to demonstrate the simplicity of what you want to do here is the code using MgntUtils library. (I tested the code and it works like a charm)

```
private static void testHttpClient() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.setContentType("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    client.setConnectionUrl("https://www.reddit.com/r/tech/top.json?limit=100");
    String content = null;
    try {
        content = client.sendHttpRequest(HttpMethod.GET);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        content = client.getLastResponseMessage() + TextUtils.getStacktrace(e, false);
    }
    System.out.println(content);
}
```